# СЕО и редирект — кому поисковик передаст рейтинг?

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы

Вот есть пример такого кода установленного на сайте http://megasite.xx/ с высоким ТИЦ и PR

```
<a href="http://site.xx/"><img src="http://site.xx/img.png"></a>
```

**Вопрос**

**1.** Какому сайту будет начисляться рейтинг в поисковой выдаче? (какому домену)

При переходе на сайт http://site.xx/ происходит редирект на сайт http://topsite.xx/

**2.** А что будет если сделать редирект и у картинки?

При загрузке картинки с сайта http://site.xx/img.png происходит редирект на картинку http://topsite.xx/img.png

Answer (score 2):

Если меня не подводит память, есть два основных применяемых редиректов в сео:

```
301 - перемещено постоянно
302 - перемещено временно
```

При 301-ом происходит склейка сайта и рейтинг переходит со старого домена на новый, поэтому несмотря на ссылку на сайт site.xx рейтинг пойдет сайту topsite.xx. Конечно для поискового робота переброс рейтинга может занять время.

При 302-ом склейки не происходит и рейтинг начисляется только сайту site.xx.

То есть при 301 в обоих случаях рейтинг пойдет topsite.xx, а при 302 только site.xx. Все остальные редиректы являются небезопасными и реакция роботов на них может быть непредсказуемая.